# How to add discount field to add divs script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

this is what i have so far.
https://jsfiddle.net/thvinic/0g8pnqk2/

I would like an input field to add the discount and it returns the discount value in

```js
var total = $('.somar').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
    var numero = el.innerHTML.split('.').join('').split(',').join('.');
    return tot + Number(numero);
}, 0);
$('#resultado').html(total.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="somar">500</div>
<div class="somar">1.000</div>
<div class="somar">1.000</div>
<div id="resultado"></div>

<div id="discount"></div>
```

tank's for helps! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to try on your own and ask for help with specific issues or errors you encounter along the way.

Here is your solution:

- Added a input field with the id `discountInput` is added to enter the
  discount value.
- Added a button with the id `calculateDiscount` is added to trigger the
  discount calculation. When the button is clicked, it retrieves the discount value from the input field and subtracts it from the total.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var total = $('.somar')
            .get()
            .reduce(function (tot, el) {
                var numero = el.innerHTML.split('.').join('').split(',').join('.');
                return tot + Number(numero);
            }, 0);

        $('#resultado').html(total.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));

        $('#calculateDiscount').click(function () {
            var discountValue = parseFloat($('#discountInput').val() || 0);
            var discountedTotal = total - discountValue;

            if (discountedTotal < 0) {
                discountedTotal = 0;
            }

            $('#discount').html(
                'Discounted Total: ' + discountedTotal.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 2 })
            );
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="somar">500</div>
<div class="somar">1.000</div>
<div class="somar">1.000</div>
<div id="resultado"></div>

<div>
    <label for="discountInput">Enter Discount:</label>
    <input type="number" id="discountInput"/>
    <button id="calculateDiscount">Calculate Discount</button>
</div>

<div id="discount"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you were amazing my friend! it was exactly what I needed!